# Get XHR info from URL

Tags: python, html, json

I have this website https://www.futbin.com/22/player/7504 and I want to know if there is a way to get the XHR url for the information using python. For example for the URL above I know the XHR I want is https://www.futbin.com/22/playerPrices?player=231443 (got it from inspect element -> network).

My objective is to get the price value from https://www.futbin.com/22/player/1 to https://www.futbin.com/22/player/10000 at once without using inspect element one by one.

```
import requests

URL = 'https://www.futbin.com/22/playerPrices?player=231443'

page = requests.get(URL)
x = page.json()
data = x['231443']['prices']
print(data['pc']['LCPrice'])
print(data['ps']['LCPrice'])
print(data['xbox']['LCPrice'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the player-resource id and build the url yourself. I use beautifulsoup. It's made for parsing websites, but you can take the requests content and throw that into an html parser as well if you don't want to install beautifulsoup

With it, read the first url, get the id and use your code to pull the prices. To test, change the 10000 to 2 or 3 and you'll see it works.

```
import re, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for i in range(1,10000):
    url = 'https://www.futbin.com/22/player/{}'.format(str(i))
    html = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    player_resource = soup.find(id=re.compile('page-info')).get('data-player-resource')
# print(player_resource)

    URL = 'https://www.futbin.com/22/playerPrices?player={}'.format(player_resource)
page = requests.get(URL)
    x = page.json()
# print(x)
    data = x[player_resource]['prices']
    print(data['pc']['LCPrice'])
    print(data['ps']['LCPrice'])
print(data['xbox']['LCPrice'])
```

Comment: you are a god, I will need to improve the speed but i have time to search

Comment: You’re welcome. Might want to look into multiprocessing or threading. Good luck!